# Webdriver Manager

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

```
public class MyDriverManager {
private WebDriver webdriver;
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass()
{
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
}
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod()
{
    webdriver=new ChromeDriver();
    webdriver.manage().window().maximize();
}
@AfterMethod
public  void AfterMethod()
{
    webdriver.close();
}
@Test
public  void test()
{
    webdriver.get("http://www.google.com/");
}

}
```

On running `@Test`, I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException as an error, Anyone, please let me know where I have committed the mistake.
Also, is there any feasible way to use it in the framework so that I can access my feature file?
I tried it using in the RunnerClass but doesn't seem to be the right way to proceed.

Comment: as far as i remember for chrome you need to install a driver first. http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads . Try with firefox and see if code is working since connection to browser is suported by default.

Comment: @TraianGEICU  I am getting the same error with firefox

Comment: @TraianGEICU We use WbedriverManager so that we can run our automation script on any browser without downloading the  .exe file

Comment: If u are using cucumber why use a Test annotation? Better option would be to initialize the webdriver in the Before and After hook. Move the beforeclass method inside the runner to setup the webdrivermanager

Comment: I agree with @Grasshopper. In runner class, move your setup scripts to beforeclass method.

Comment: @shreyashshukla can you tell us exactly how you are running the test ? using something like maven or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you directly run your @Test, I'm assuming you are using some IDE and right clicking on the @Test annotation and running it.
If thats the case, chances are that your **@BeforeMethod** is not getting called, hence WebDriver is coming up as **null**

To verify this, you can debug or put some kind of print statement to check.

Use below code to verify the error if you are NOT DEBUGGING (just modified your code)

```
public class MyDriverManager {
private WebDriver webdriver;
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass()
{
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
}
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod()
{
    System.out.println( " control is inside beforeMethod now");
    webdriver=new ChromeDriver();
    webdriver.manage().window().maximize();
}
@AfterMethod
public  void AfterMethod()
{
    webdriver.close();
}
@Test
public  void test()
{
    System.out.println( " control is inside test method now");
    webdriver.get("http://www.google.com/");
}

}
```